# Using a header-only C++ library for efficient GPU multidimensional integration in Rcpp

Tags: c++, gpu, rcpp, numerical-integration

I would like to use a portable header-only c++ library that perform multidimensional integration in a rather efficient way. It particular it makes use of parallelisation and GPU processors: https://github.com/marcpaterno/gpuintegration

The header I would like to use is called `mcubes`, which is inside the `cuda` folder.

My goal is to use this library in `R` through `Rcpp`.

I tried to use their test case, called `seqGenz3_3D.cpp`, inside the demos folder.
So I edited in order to be used with `Rcpp`:

```
#include "cuda/mcubes/mcubesSeq.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class GENZ_3_3D {
  public:
    __device__ __host__ double
    operator()(double x, double y, double z)
    {
      return pow(1 + 3 * x + 2 * y + z, -4);
    }
  };


 template <typename T, int NDIM>
  struct Volume {

    T lows[NDIM] = {0.0};
    T highs[NDIM];

    __host__
    Volume()
    {
      for (T& x : highs)
        x = 1.0;
    }

    __host__
    Volume(std::array<T, NDIM> l, std::array<T, NDIM> h)
    {
      std::memcpy(lows, l.data(), NDIM * sizeof(T));
      std::memcpy(highs, h.data(), NDIM * sizeof(T));
    }

    __host__ __device__
    Volume(T const* l, T const* h)
    {
      std::memcpy(lows, l, NDIM * sizeof(T));
      std::memcpy(highs, h, NDIM * sizeof(T));
    }
  };


  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  auto InteResults(double epsrel, double ncall, int titer){

    double epsrel = 1e-3;

    double ncall = 1.0e7;
    int titer = 20;
    constexpr int ndim = 3;

    double lows[] = {0., 0., 0.};
    double highs[] = {1., 1., 1.};
    quad::Volume<double, ndim> volume(lows, highs);
    GENZ_3_3D integrand;
    auto res =  seq_mcubes_integrate<GENZ_3_3D, ndim>(integrand, ndim, epsrel, 1.e-12, ncall,  &volume, titer);
    return res;
  }
```

However, when I try to run it in R using Rcpp (typing sourceCpp('test.cpp')), I get the following error:

```
In file included from SeqGen3D.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/mcubesSeq.hh:17:
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:17:5: error: unknown type name '__host__'
    __host__
    ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:18:5: error: constructor cannot have a return type
    Volume()
    ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:24:5: error: unknown type name '__host__'
    __host__
    ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:25:5: error: constructor cannot have a return type
    Volume(std::array<T, NDIM> l, std::array<T, NDIM> h)
    ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:31:5: error: unknown type name '__host__'
    __host__ __device__
    ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/pagani/quad/util/Volume.cuh:31:24: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    __host__ __device__
                       ^
                       ;
In file included from SeqGen3D.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/mcubesSeq.hh:19:
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:38:1: error: unknown type name '__host__'
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:38:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
                   ^
                   ;
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:38:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:39:6: error: unknown type name 'T'
IMAX(T a, U b)
     ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:39:11: error: unknown type name 'U'
IMAX(T a, U b)
          ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:45:1: error: unknown type name '__host__'
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:45:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
                   ^
                   ;
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:45:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
__host__ __device__ std::common_type_t<T, U>
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:46:6: error: unknown type name 'T'
IMIN(T a, U b)
     ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:46:11: error: unknown type name 'U'
IMIN(T a, U b)
          ^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:52:1: error: unknown type name '__host__'
__host__ __device__ T
^
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:52:20: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
__host__ __device__ T
                   ^
                   ;
/usr/local/include/cuda/mcubes/seqCodesDefs.hh:52:21: error: unknown type name 'T'
__host__ __device__ T
                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [SeqGen3D.o] Error 1
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `__host__` seems to be a - potentially compiler specific - macro which you are missing. You can try to define it away - `#define __host__` - and see if it works. Otherwise, find out what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got the same error. I will try to find out what actually is. But perhaps, people with more C++ experience may spot the problem.

Comment: Sure… I only code C++ professionally since 1990, good luck. My guess is you missed an ‘_’ or your issue is really Rust related.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that you are not an expert. I meant that letting people with C++ experience proposing a solution may be more efficient than me 'swimming' in the ocean of C++ codes. BTW, yes, I think that my issue is R related, as in here http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~cr173/Sta790_Sp19/slides/Lec13.html#10    or  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225517/build-r-package-with-relocatable-device-code

Comment: Every GPU / NVidia I know of suggests to use a different compiler / `nvcc` as a frontend to `gcc`.  The packages that work(ed) with R, Rcpp and GPU all mixed compilation of pure GPU code via `nvcc` and standard code so your approach of throwing it all at the same compiler (provided by R) may be doomed.